# How to convert *.vue example files for CDN use?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am looking at the example files of [vuetify](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/layouts/layouts/demos/baseline.vue). They all seem to be *.vue files. I am only familiar with *.html *.css *.js files where [vue is used with CDN](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#cdn-usage). How to convert/modify these vue files for CDN use? what are the steps? What are the pitfalls in doing so?

I am a beginner in vue.js and currently prototyping a tiny application to input/output few data and nothing fancy is required. CDN fits well for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at first I would always recommend going with the Vue CLI instead of the CDN usage because it brings you a lot of benefits and a overall smoother developer expierence.

Coming to your question: Here is the starter template for Vuetify with a CDN https://codepen.io/pen?template=OJJeVge

They simply use the vuetify components inside a `<script>` tag with an id and mount that and initialize the vue instance with it.

You would put all other data stuff inside the `<script>` tag like you would do inside the script tag of a normal .vue file.